# HPUX Apache 2.2.15 not starting?

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, hp-ux

Ive been looking for 2 days anything similar or related to the error that im getting for my apache.

Im using 2.2.15 which is the version allowed by my company policies to install in an hpux server, after i complete the install i try to run the server and even when it starts for a second after then it shuts down itself with the following:

```
Sat Dec 13 00:18:37 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 HP-UX_Apache-based_Web_Server (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/0.9.8zb configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Dec 13 00:18:37 2014] [info] Server built: Jul 11 2014 12:41:45
[Sat Dec 13 00:18:37 2014] [debug] worker.c(1875): AcceptMutex: sysvsem (default: sysvsem)
[Sat Dec 13 00:18:37 2014] [error] (14)Bad address: apr_socket_accept: (client socket)
[Sat Dec 13 00:18:38 2014] [error] (14)Bad address: apr_socket_accept: (client socket)
[Sat Dec 13 00:18:38 2014] [debug] worker.c(1434): taking over scoreboard slot from 23152 (quiescing)
[Sat Dec 13 00:18:39 2014] [alert] No active workers found... Apache is exiting!
```

Ive tried using the only ip the server has, the loopback, the hostname...well everything and everytime i get the same error log. The ulimit set high around 6048 for processes and open files, I even have another apache running in the box its older but its running.

I didnot compiled the apache i downloaded the depot file from hp software page the hp web server suite do you think that could be the issue?

Do you have any idea where did i messed this thing up?

Comment: Sounds like it is not configured properly.

Comment: Even with the default config and starting it up, its showing the same error. Everytime i test i shut down the older apache to be sure that is not a port conflict or anything

Comment: Any one faced this issue before guys? What if i leave apache to listen in all interfaces could that fix it?